# Custom Background Resizing As Needed

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, background, resize

Is it possible to make a square pattern gradient coloured background that resizes as a webpage grows downwards?

A square pattern, dark color - light color - dark color etc and as it goes up it gets ligther (gradient vertically) and, the important thing here, how to make the pattern increase as needed, because I don't know much about photoshop but as far as I know I have to choose the dimensions of a project 900x500(«height) however, the height grows as I add stuff to the div container... (the gradient would also have to redo or something)

Is this done in HTML/CSS or a photoshop setting? Or I have to make a big background and make it appear as user scrolls down?

Comment: Could you give an example to the square pattern you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you could overlay two `div`s, one with your pattern and `background-repeat: repeat;` on the bottom and one with a flexible gradient from white to transparent on top. This [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) has helped me lots.

Comment: Cool :oo imma see if it works out

Comment: Also, "vote up requires 15 reputation" so no votes for you sir :[

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create an image and use the `background-size` CSS property.

[More information on background-size here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Basically it tells the image to scale to match the window size or scale to match whatever size you've declared.

Be aware you may need to use [vendor prefixes](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific) to get things working correctly and this isn't supported in older web browsers.

It would be helpful to see a sample of the image you wish to use.

Comment: I don't have one yet! (Although was conserning on how would I do it to resize and that if the div got bigger) But I'll look into your info. Thanks!